# How to pass an HTML Select tag using Javascript and Ajax to PHP $_POST with one (array) var when the name attribute is an array

Tags: javascript, html

These links:

"[How to modify an HTML Select when the name is an array using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1339571/3530269)"

and
"[How to pass an array from HTML to Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342218/how-to-pass-an-array-from-html-to-javascript)"

blinds me on what if i have select tags with 2 or more different names like:

```
<select name='category[123]'>
    <option value='0'>off</option>
    <option value='1'>on</option>
</select>

<select name='category[456]'>
    <option value='0'>off</option>
    <option value='1'>on</option>
</select>

<select name='anothercategory[123]'>
    <option value='0'>off</option>
    <option value='1'>on</option>
</select>

<select name='anothercategory[456]'>
    <option value='0'>off</option>
    <option value='1'>on</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you need this values with ajax request or form submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$("form").serialize()` for posting all values from the form.

Comment: i'm testing something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398783/jquery-form-serialize-and-other-parameters

Comment: and data : $('form').serialize() + "&othervariable=othervarvalue" works!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get values one by one you can use this example as well.

```
var category_id    = $('#category').val()
var form_data      = { category : category_id };
data    : form_data,
```

Now you can get category values where you need it.